# How do I detect and connect to a hidden SSID on my Raspiberry Pi 3 (Raspbian)?

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, hidden, ssid, raspberry-pi3

How do I configure my Raspberry Pi 3 (running Raspbian) to connect to a hidden network? I know it involves editing the /etc/network/interfaces file and the wpa_supplicant.conf file. I've followed a few other guides, but when I make these file changes and reboot, I can't even detect visible networks, as they disappear from my wifi menu. I think I'm just editing these files with incorrect configurations.

Comment: I unhid the network, connected once, then hid the network again and it connected automatically.
There was a 30-45 second delay after a reboot before it connected...

Answer (score 24):

I have a Pi 3.  Including or excluding `country=US` had no effect.
editing the wpa_supplicant.conf file to look like this:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    scan_ssid=1
    ssid="NAME"
    psk="password"
}
```

removing `key_mgmt=WPA-PSK` and rebooting worked for me.

Comment: I struggled with this too - most of the advice is for version other than 3, or out of date. 

This is a year old, so you've probably fixed this but it was a top Google result so for everyone else:

- for Pi 3b+ with Stretch, scan_ssid did not work for me -  needed to use priority=x where 0 is the default and higher numbers are evaluated in descending order. This definitely works on a Pi 3b+ running Stretch as of this writing.

Comment: Hm, this worked perfectly for me on a RPi3 B+; scan_ssid=1 did work and I didn't need priority

Comment: I have a RPi 4 Model B, and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 23):

First, enter the following in the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Edit the interfaces file to look like so, which shouldn't be too different from the default:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

Next, we will edit the wpa_supplicant.conf file. Enter the following in the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Edit the settings of this configuration file to be as such:

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1 
network={
        scan_ssid=1
        ssid="Your Hidden SSID"
        psk="Your SSID's Password"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK }
```

Note: You will need to change the "country" setting based on your location. Also, scan_ssid must be set to 1 to be able to detect a hidden SSID. Input your SSID name and password for your hidden network. Save these changes, reboot your raspberry pi, and then it should be automatically connected to the hidden network upon returning to the desktop.

Comment: Worked on Raspberry Pi 0 W. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**1.** To connect to a hidden network yo need to modify only /etc/wpa_supplicant/***wpa_supplicant.conf***

```
network={
       ssid="your SSID"
       scan_ssid=1
       psk=your PSK 
}
```

I create this file and encrypted using `wpa_passphrase "your PSK" "your SSID"` command

**2.** /etc/network/***interfaces*** does not need to be modify by you if you need to connect to your hidden network. When you modify ***wpa_supplicant.conf*** file in the ***interfaces*** file is created a new configuration automatically. In my case it looks like:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf  /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf


allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf  /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Be sure when you add a new network on wpa_supplicant.conf file does not exist any conflict with the IPs allowed in the /etc/dhcpch.conf file...

For more information you can check: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md

Answer (score 4):

I have a **Raspberry Pi 3 (Model B)** running **Raspbian 9 (Stretch)**,
this network interface configuration worked for me to connect to my routers hidden SSID (**TP Link Archer 2600, secured with WPA/WPA-2 Personal**).

1) `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

####################################################
##### custom stuff to find hidden router SSIDs #####
####################################################
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Note that I only set up `loopback` and `wlan0` (wireless) interfaces, I didn't need the `eth0` (wired connection) interface.

2) `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
country=SE
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
ap_scan=1
update_config=1
network={
    scan_ssid=1
    ssid="xxx"
    psk="xxx"
}
```

Make sure to set up your `country`, `ssid` and `psk` appropriately.
`ssid` is the hidden SSID of your router or access point.
`psk` is the passphrase to connect and authenticate to the router or access point.

3) `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

I didn't have to change anything in `dhcpcd.conf`.

Comment: Worked for me on Pi 3 B+.

Answer (score 4):

On Raspberry Pi 4, it works right after the initial configuration, but will not work after a reboot. You can fix that by editing `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` to add `scan_ssid=1` to the target network configuration. It would end up looking like this:

```
network={
       ssid="your SSID"
       psk="your PSK"
       ...
       scan_ssid=1
}
```

After a reboot, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

**Requirement of Raspberry Pi System:**

1. Raspberry Pi 3 B+ ( Raspbian Strecth Operating System )
2. List the all available hidden wifi.

**Steps to Follow**

First open the terminal then type:

sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

Add the following:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=IN
network={
        ssid="XXXXXXXX"
        priority=1
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
        pairwise=CCMP
        auth_alg=OPEN
        eap=PEAP
        identity="18XXXXXXXX3"
        password=hash:d7XXXXXXXXXXXxXXXxce
        phase1="peaplabel=0"
        phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

Save the file and exit the wpa_supplicant.conf.
Your need to give your hidden wifi name in place of ssid, user ID in place of identity and Password need to converted into hash code format.

Use this command in terminal to convert your password into hash code format.

```
echo -n 'YOUR_REAL_PASSWORD' | iconv -t utf16le | openssl md4 > hash.txt
```

Next Do the following:

1. sudo nano hash.txt
2. Insert hash: in place of (stdin)=
3. Copy the entire text and exit
4. Next modify the password in wpa_supplicant.conf file and exit

Reboot the system.

**Expected Output**

It will connect to Hidden ssid

Answer (score 2):

Tried all the previously changes on my Pi4, but I still had no success.
Kept trying to disable/enable the network, and restarting my PI, but still not connecting.

I have eventually found the issue by accident by doing this command:
iwlist wlan0 scan ssid "your ssid"

This have then activated the Pi to search and connect to the hidden network.