# Trouble connecting to hidden SSID with Raspi 3 running Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi3, ssid

I have tried the method outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312501/how-do-i-detect-and-connect-to-a-hidden-ssid-on-my-raspiberry-pi-3-raspbian/37312502) without any success. After editing the files as indicated, saving and rebooting, I still don't have a connection. Mousing over the network connections on the task bar indicates "eth0: Link is down" and "wlan0: Not associated."

If someone would be able to point me in the right direction, that would be super. I would have just commented on the linked question, but I can't do so as a new user.

Comment: You essentially say that the described method does not work for you. Without further information it will be difficult to find out why.

Comment: What more information would be pertinent? The Pi was fresh out of the box and the only thing I did before trying to connect using the given method was use NOOBS to load the Raspbian OS.

Comment: Actually, I don't know which information would be crucial here, but how should an outsider guess what could solve the problem? The most likely thing would be that you have a typo in some config file. The second most likely thing is that your version of the OS or some hardware component does not exactly match the required version.

Comment: Managed to fix the issue. Being a beginner, I misunderstood the syntax used by Nano.